# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on iOS in system libraries

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, exception, exc-bad-access

I'm having an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception in an iOS game made in Xcode. It happens on the Simulator and on real devices. It's always at the same part in the game, but does not always happen. It's cryptic because it does not seem to have anything to do with the game's objects, just with default library/system methods. Xcode also does not show which line of code is causing it (but it shows which line in *assembly*). I'm posting the backtrace below. What could be causing it? How can I find out what is the problem?

```
thread #1: tid = 0x1c03, 0x01980051 libobjc.A.dylib`_cache_getImp + 9, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xc0000008)
frame #0: 0x01980051 libobjc.A.dylib`_cache_getImp + 9
frame #1: 0x0196dac4 libobjc.A.dylib`lookUpMethod + 42
frame #2: 0x0196da88 libobjc.A.dylib`class_respondsToSelector + 65
frame #3: 0x023160d3 CoreFoundation`objectIsKindOfClass + 51
frame #4: 0x0239f087 CoreFoundation`__handleUncaughtException + 71
frame #5: 0x0196f0b9 libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 86
frame #6: 0x01da2a65 libc++abi.dylib`safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 13
frame #7: 0x01da2acd libc++abi.dylib`std::terminate() + 23
frame #8: 0x01da3c4e libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_rethrow + 83
frame #9: 0x0196efbd libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_rethrow + 47
frame #10: 0x022bbf98 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 360
frame #11: 0x022bbe1b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
frame #12: 0x01df57e3 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 88
frame #13: 0x01df5668 GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
frame #14: 0x00aa5ffc UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1211
frame #15: 0x000026e1 Game`main(argc=1, argv=0xbffff3bc) + 95 at main.m:6
frame #16: 0x00002645 Game`start + 53
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an uncaught exception.  There should be a log message the describes the exception that was thrown.

---

Ew.... ugly... it is a malformed exception causing the crash.

Quite likely, your app is corrupting memory somehow.   Create an exception breakpoint (it is in the debugger UI) and see if you can get it to break in the debugger.  Since it is a rethrow() in the backtrace, the original throw may actually be useful.

Comment: You mean it should appear on the same console as NSLogs? There's nothing there, besides my own logs.

Comment: Exception breakpoint: +100!  Can't believe I didn't know about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I too am seeing an EXC_BAD_ACCESS with this stack trace that is the result of raising an NSException in the DisplayLink's handler. For example:

```
#0  0x01142e52 in objc_exception_throw ()
#1  0x01d04deb in +[NSException raise:format:] ()
#2  0x00005502 in -[ViewController glkView:drawInRect:] at ViewController.m:225
#3  0x010e8675 in -[GLKView _display:] ()
#4  0x010e8c89 in -[GLKView display] ()
#5  0x010e9ab7 in -[GLKViewController _updateAndDraw] ()
#6  0x01156663 in -[NSObject performSelector:] ()
#7  0x010e900f in -[GLKDisplayLinkMessenger message] ()
#8  0x0231f2d2 in CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch(unsigned long long, unsigned long long) ()
#9  0x0231f75f in CA::Display::TimerDisplayLink::callback(__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*) ()
#10 0x01cc4376 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#11 0x01cc3e06 in __CFRunLoopDoTimer ()
#12 0x01caba82 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#13 0x01caaf44 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific () 
#14 0x01caae1b in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#15 0x01c5f7e3 in GSEventRunModal ()
#16 0x01c5f668 in GSEventRun ()
#17 0x0001a65c in UIApplicationMain ()
```

This repro was produced by raising an exception in the -[ViewController glkView:drawInRect:] function of the OpenGL Game application template in Xcode 4.6.2.

Interestingly, it repros on both device and simulator running iOS 6.0+, but not on iOS 5.1.

After poking around, it appears that in iOS 6.0+, an autorelease pool was added to DisplayLink::Dispatch, and it appears to be dalloc'ing the NSException prior to the unhandled exception handler getting a chance at it:

```
#0     0x01d07470 in -[NSException dealloc] ()
#1     0x011569ff in -[NSObject release] ()
#2     0x011550d5 in objc_release ()
#3     0x01155bd9 in (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) ()
#4     0x01ca7468 in _CFAutoreleasePoolPop ()
#5     0x0230ffc1 in CA::AutoreleasePool::~AutoreleasePool() ()
#6     0x0231f3d2 in CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch(unsigned long long, unsigned long  long) ()
#7     0x0231f75f in CA::Display::TimerDisplayLink::callback(__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*) ()
#8     0x01cc4376 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#9     0x01cc3e06 in __CFRunLoopDoTimer ()
#10     0x01caba82 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#11     0x01caaf44 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#12     0x01caae1b in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#13     0x01c5f7e3 in GSEventRunModal ()
#14     0x01c5f668 in GSEventRun ()
#15     0x0001a65c in UIApplicationMain ()
#16     0x00002c3d in main
```

This autorelease pool seems to have been put in place in iOS 6.0.

Possible workaround: catch all NSExceptions in your CADisplayLink target function, then either manually retain them and rethrow, or invoke your unhandled exception handler, then abort.